# Initial value problem 4

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Which option is true for question which is as fallows:

> The differential equation 
>   $$\begin{cases} y'=60(y^2)^{\frac{1}{5}} , x>0 \\y(0)=0 \end{cases}$$
>   has:
>   1. a unique solution
>   2. two solutions
>   3. no solution
>   4. infinite number of solution

I have solved it by variable separable method and I got only one solution
Please make me sure that I'm right or wrong.

Comment: What is the solution that you got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two solutions:

1. The trivial solution $y=0$.
2. The solution you get from variable separation.

Comment: i got it'' thanx